# How to get 5day weather forecast from openweathermap to my uwp app

Tags: c#, uwp, openweathermap

I'm not an experienced developer. I'm just a noob to programming.

I've managed to get current weather info to my app via this url `http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=7.0744&lon=79.8919&appid=a7cae8ecfab2535dec05a83525f5ac7a`

but I don't know how to get 5day weather forecast data from this openweathermap url  `http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=7.0744&lon=79.8919&appid=a7cae8ecfab2535dec05a83525f5ac7a`

this is the Weatherforecast class i created

```
 class WeatherForecast
{
    public async static Task<RootObject> GetWeatherForecast(double lat,double lon)
    {
        var httpn = new HttpClient();
        var uri = String.Format("http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat={0}&lon={1}&appid=a7cae8ecfab2535dec05a83525f5ac7a", lat, lon);
        var response = await httpn.GetAsync(uri);
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);

        return data;


    }

}
public class Main
{
    public double temp { get; set; }
    public double temp_min { get; set; }
    public double temp_max { get; set; }
    public double pressure { get; set; }
    public double sea_level { get; set; }
    public double grnd_level { get; set; }
    public int humidity { get; set; }
    public int temp_kf { get; set; }
}

public class Weather
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string main { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
}

public class Clouds
{
    public int all { get; set; }
}

public class Wind
{
    public double speed { get; set; }
    public double deg { get; set; }
}

public class Rain
{
}

public class Sys
{
    public string pod { get; set; }
}

public class List
{
    public int dt { get; set; }
    public Main main { get; set; }
    public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
    public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
    public Wind wind { get; set; }
    public Rain rain { get; set; }
    public Sys sys { get; set; }
    public string dt_txt { get; set; }
}

public class Coord
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lon { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Coord coord { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string cod { get; set; }
    public double message { get; set; }
    public int cnt { get; set; }
    public List<List> list { get; set; }
    public City city { get; set; }
}
```

`

This is the the click event of getweatherforcast button (I added a button to get forcast)

```
    private async void ForecastButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var position1 = await LocationManager.GetPosition();
        var latitude1 = position1.Coordinate.Latitude;
        var longitude1 = position1.Coordinate.Longitude;
        UWPWeatherforMobileForeCast.RootObject forecast = await WeatherForecast.GetWeatherForecast(latitude1, longitude1);

    }
```

This is the Gridview I want to bind data

```
   <GridView x:Name="ForecastGridView" >
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Name="forecastdatetextblock"/>
                        <TextBlock Name="forecasttemptextblock" />
                        <TextBlock Name="forecastdescriptiontextblock"/>
                     </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
```

How to bind 5day forecast date,temp and description to this gridview. what kind of itemsource and data type should I use?

[This is a screenshot of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIw1a.jpg)
it's a  very simple app for my education purposes. I want to bind date,temp,description on to a gridview in that area I drawn.

p.s. this is my first stackoverflow question so forgive me if there any mistakes

Comment: Have you started to get data with JSON or just convert JSON To C# ?
If yes, post your methods to get JSON and we will help you...
If not, we not code it for you. 
Please be more explicit next time :)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I added the code I wrote.

Comment: I guess this will help you https://openweathermap.org/forecast5

Comment: What you get is just a data model. Prepare ViewModel (e.g. MyViewViewModel) and then inside create collection e.g. IEnumerable<ForecastVM>. That will give you flexibility and you will not be dependent on the data you get. Then you will be able to fill the collection with e.g. 5 days from the model you fetched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to bind 5day forecast date,temp and description to this gridview. what kind of itemsource and data type should I use?

After you get the `RootObject` object in the button click event, you should operate the data to get five days weather and make them display on the UI. Here is a simple example code to bind 5 days weather to the UI, you can have a reference. (Click the button to get the 5 day whether data and display them)

**This is the xaml**

```
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Content="get whether" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding collection}" x:Name="ForecastGridView">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Name="forecastdatetextblock" Text="{Binding dt}"/>
                    <TextBlock Name="forecasttemptextblock" Text="{Binding main.temp}" />
                    <TextBlock Name="forecastdescriptiontextblock"  Text="{Binding weather[0].description}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</StackPanel>
```

**This is the code behind**

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    collection = new ObservableCollection<List>();
    this.DataContext = this;
}

public ObservableCollection<List> collection { get; set; }
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var position1 = await LocationManager.GetPosition();
    var latitude1 = position1.Coordinate.Latitude;
    var longitude1 = position1.Coordinate.Longitude;
    RootObject forecast = await WeatherForecast.GetWeatherForecast(latitude1, longitude1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {

        collection.Add(forecast.list[i]);
    }

    ForecastGridView.ItemsSource = collection;

}
```